# Finding a specific sequence of elements in a list, prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have to write a predicate that takes a List and succeeds if the list contains elements "a, b, c"in that order anywhere in the list, other wise it fails. I am pretty lost on where to start(not looking for a solution, just a hint to the right direction).

Comment: A list that has `X`, `Y`, and `Z` as its first 3 elements can be represented as `[X, Y, Z | T]` where `T` is a list representing the tail or rest of the list. So at least you know what a list that starts with `a`, `b`, and `c` (in that order) looks like. You might want to try the Prolog tutorial at [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/).

Comment: do you mean that "a, x, b, x, c" is a good list or not? because you say "in that order anywhere in the list" but some answers tell you that you have them right after one another.

Comment: Not all answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42388532/7201281 - although I'm beginning to wonder if I overcomplicated things...

Comment: @JimAshworth sorry i missed your answer it is very difficult when all code is not visible to read the answer

Comment: @User9213 I fully understand - when answering questions that specifically ask for 'not a solution' I try to make my answer a jack-of-all-trades - namely, hint to those who want it, answer to those who need it - sometimes at the cost of readability

Answer (score 4):

## Declarative wording

Almost always, when a Prolog task is formulated in a rather *imperative* way, the solution will be comparatively limited. This means that we typically can only use it in a few modes and directions, while other modes may even yield wrong results.

Therefore, I suggest to use more *declarative* wording.

You say:

> a predicate that **takes** a list and **succeeds** if the list **contains** elements "a, b, c" in that order anywhere in the list, otherwise it **fails**.

That's a rather *procedural* way to look at this. Note that in Prolog, any argument can also be a logical *variable*, and thus there may not even be a list to "take". Instead, we expect the predicate to **generate** such lists in these cases!

Watch your wording! Very often, when you are able to express the task *declaratively*, an elegant and general Prolog solution will be straight-forward and often follows quite naturally from the task description.

## Describing solutions

First, let us focus on **what holds**. There is no need to express what *doesn't hold*, because the predicate *will not succeed* anyways in such cases.

What do we want to *describe*?

Essentially, we want to *describe* lists of the form `[...,a,b,c,...]`.

There are already some answers, with various drawbacks.

A **pure** way to do it uses the meta-predicate `if_/3` from [*Indexing dif/2*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590):

```
abc([X,Y,Z|Vs]) :-
        if_((X=a,Y=b,Z=c), true, abc([Y,Z|Vs])).
```

## Generality

This works in all directions. First, let us try the **most general** query, where the single argument is a fresh *variable*:

```
?- abc(Vs).
Vs = [a, b, c|_5032] ;
Vs = [a, b, a, b, c|_5144] ;
Vs = [a, b, a, b, a, b, c|_5286] .
```

Thus, we can *generate* solutions, which is a very nice property of a relation!

The predicate is *monotonic*, and therefore *iterative deepening* is possible to *fairly* enumerate answers:

```
?- length(Vs, _), abc(Vs).
Vs = [a, b, c] ;
Vs = [a, b, c, _11600] ;
Vs = [a, a, b, c] ;
Vs = [_11982, a, b, c],
dif(_11982, a) ;
Vs = [a, b, c, _11600, _11606] .
```

From this, it follows that there are *no solutions* with less than 3 elements. In this case, that's quite obvious. In other cases, such results may be much less obvious from the task description.

## Efficiency

The predicate is **deterministic** if its argument is sufficiently instantiated.

For example:

```
?- abc([a,b,c]).
true.

?- abc([z,a,b,c]).
true.

?- abc([a,b,c,z]).
true.
```

Note that *no choice points* remain in these cases!

Comment: Thanks for giving the pure answer before me. I was trying to use (-> ;) and because of your answer learned, (if_). Thanks. :)

Comment: Great! `if_/3`, `tfilter/3` and `cond_t/3` are powerful new meta-predicates that are now available in `library(reif)`. It took decades to find these constructs, and now they are finally available. I think they will be very useful for us in the coming decades to increase generality and efficiency of many Prolog programs that were almost impossible to write elegantly only a few years ago. Happy puring, and I'm looking forward to seeing your answer for the next tasks of this kind!

Comment: Where can I find good documentation on `if_/3`, `tfilter/3` and `cond_t/3`. I can find them used in questions and mentioned in articles, but nothing that documents each one specifically.

Comment: @GuyCoder: There's the mentioned paper cited above. [And don't forget this](https://youtu.be/kZRKjY9NijY)!

Answer (score 2):

Here are three approaches you could take, in roughly ascending order by flexibility:

First, is to use the predicate [nth0/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3) to find the position of a, b, and c in the list, and then check that the position of a < position of b < position of c. For multiple instances of a, b, and c in the list (e.g. [c,b,a,b,c,a]) nth0 will find positions of each matching element in turn, such that if there are three positions that fit the criteria (even if they are not the first positions) the predicate will succeed.

Hint 1.1: The syntax for nth0 to find the position of a.

> `nth0(PositionA,[c,b,a,b,c,a],a)`

Hint 1.2: The syntax of less than (for completeness)

> `PositionA < PositionB`

Partial Solution 1: A sequence of commands using nth0 to check that a, b, and c appear in some order in the list [c,b,a,b,c,a] (assembling the predicate is left to you)

> `nth0(PositionA,[c,b,a,b,c,a],a),`
>  `nth0(PositionB,[c,b,a,b,c,a],b),`
>  `nth0(PositionC,[c,b,a,b,c,a],c),`
>  `PositionA < PositionB,`
>  `PositionB < PositionC.`

Second approach uses list pattern matching - we observe that, when going down the list, we must encounter a, then b, then c. To do that, we can construct three predicates that find a, b, and c, and then pass on the rest of the list where appropriate. We must construct these predicates to ignore other elements until they see their target.

Hint 2.1: The head of a predicate where a is the first element of the list

> `find_a([a|Rest]) :-`

Hint 2.2: The head of a predicate where anything is the first element of the list

> `find_a([_|Rest]) :-`

Hint 2.3: When we find a, we start looking for b

> `find_a([a|Rest]) :-`
>      `find_b(Rest).`

Hint 2.4: When we don't find a, we keep looking for a

> `find_a([_|Rest]) :-`
>      `find_a(Rest).`

Hint 2.5: Order matters (kind-of)

> If we place `find_a([a|Rest])` first in the knowledge base then Prolog will always try to unify against it first, so we'll match the first a we find. If we place it second, this will still work, but with a lot of extra backtracking, and we'll find each a in reverse order.

Hint 2.6: Don't forget the base case!

> Remember that, even though you don't need to do anything once you find c, you still need to create a fact stating that it is the head of the list: `find_c([c|_]).`

The third approach is essentially a generalised version of the second approach - instead of creating predicates to find a, b, and c, you create a predicate that finds a list of elements in order.

Hint 3.1: Your predicate should take two lists and compare the heads of each

> `compare([A|Targets],[B|Checks]) :-`

Hint 3.2: If the same variable name appears in multiple places, it must have the same value for the predicate to match

> `compare([A|Targets],[A|Checks]) :- % succeeds when the same element is at the head of each list`

Hint 3.3: If they match, keep going down both lists

> `compare(Targets,Checks).`

Hint 3.4: If they don't match, only go down the Checks list

> `compare([A|Targets],Checks).`

Hint 3.5: Never forget the base case (when there are no more targets)

> `compare([],_).`

Hint 3.6: As before, ordering is still important

> `compare([A|Targets],[A|Checks]) :- ...` should be in the knowledge base before `compare(Targets,[_|Checks]) :- ...`

Solution 3:

> `compare([],_).`
>  `compare([A|Targets],[A|Checks]) :-`
>      `compare(Targets,Checks).`
>  `compare(Targets,[_|Checks]) :-`
>      `compare(Targets,Checks).`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It really would be cool if one could see all hidden text above the currently "discovered" one. Doing C-a is not the best. Maybe you want to suggest this on meta?

Comment: @false C-a? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that abbreviation - in any event, I shall take some time this evening and craft a meta-post suggesting / requesting some form of sequential spoiler, or possibly a click-to-reveal-permanently, or both

Comment: C-a = Control + a = Select all text. In this manner you can see all the invisible text - but only inverted

Comment: @false Obvious when you say it, really - I guess I'm just used to the less efficient 'ctrl + A' notation. Cheers.

Comment: @false raised here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291403/folding-sections-in-answers

Comment: I rather thought of meta.stackoverflow.com which is much more active. No rep loss for downvotes &ct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136399/discussion-between-jim-ashworth-and-false).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to describe the relation uses a grammar. You are talking about a sequence, well, that's what the [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) formalism is for!

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
abcsubsequence(Cs) :-
   phrase(abc, Cs).

abc -->
   ..., "abc", ... .
```

or alternatively, if you permit further text in between:

```
abc -->
   ..., "a", ..., "b", ..., "c", ... .
```

So what is this magic `...`? It's just any sequence:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Efficiency-wise mat's solution is much better. But for correctness reasons above versions are better since they fail for `abcsequence([a,b,c|non_list])`. However, making relations a tiny bit more general by permitting such solutions is quite common in Prolog, you just have to be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

### Finding a,b,c

To find the letters `a,b,c` in a list in that order one should start with the comment by @lurker which says `[X, Y, Z | T]`.

```erlang
has_abc([a,b,c|T]).
```

Since I am using SWI-Prolog and prefer not to receive the warning

> Warning: somecode.pl:
>           Singleton variables: [T]

I will make a small change by changing `T` to `_`

```erlang
has_abc([a,b,c|_]).
```

and then run some simple test

```erlang
?- has_abc([a,b,c]).
true.

?- has_abc([a,b,c,z]).
true.

?- has_abc([z,a,b,c]).
false.
```

As you can see the predicate `has_abc` can find `a,b,c` at the start of a list but not any place else.

### Taking a list a part

In Prolog a list can be recursively deconstructed using `[H|T]`

> deconstruct_list([Head|Tail]) :-
>          write('Head of list: '),write(Head),nl,
>          deconstruct_list(Tail).

and a few demonstration cases

```erlang
?- deconstruct_list([]).
false.

?- deconstruct_list([a]).
Head of list: a
false.

?- deconstruct_list([a,b]).
Head of list: a
Head of list: b
false.

?- deconstruct_list([a,b,c]).
Head of list: a
Head of list: b
Head of list: c
false.
```

### Putting the predicates together

Now combining the first two predicates for finding `a,b,c` and deconstructing a list gives us

> has_abc([a,b,c|_]).
>
>      has_abc([_|T]) :-
>          has_abc(T).

and a few test cases

```erlang
?- has_abc([]).
false.

?- has_abc([a]).
false.

?- has_abc([a,b]).
false.

?- has_abc([a,b,c]).
true .

?- has_abc([z,a,b,c]).
true .

?- has_abc([a,b,c,z]).
true .

?- has_abc([z,a,b,c,z]).
true .
```

### Resolving the choice-point with a cut

Almost there. There is a small problem because for the `true` answers we had to press `Enter` to exit which indicates we have a choice-point.

A way to fix this is with a `cut` (!) which say that once we have an answer stop looking for more answers.

> has_abc([a,b,c|_]) :- !.
>
>      has_abc([_|T]) :-
>          has_abc(T).

and a few test cases

```erlang
?- has_abc([]).
false.

?- has_abc([a]).
false.

?- has_abc([a,b]).
false.

?- has_abc([a,b,c]).
true.

?- has_abc([z,a,b,c]).
true.

?- has_abc([a,b,c,z]).
true.

?- has_abc([z,a,b,c,z]).
true.

?- has_abc([d]).
false.

?- has_abc([d,e]).
false.

?- has_abc([d,e,f]).
false.

?- has_abc([d,e,f,g]).
false.
```

Notice that when running the test cases one did not have to press `Enter` to end the query.

### Resolving the choice-point without a cut

See the answer by [mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393166/1243762)

Comment: That is a very red cut!